# How can I know I translated from English to predicate Logic properly

Tags: logic

I want some help. Say I want to translate this geometric theorem to logic: if E is a point on a midsegment of a trapezoid ABCD, then the sum of areas of two triangles AEB and DEC equals 1/2 the area of the trapezoid itself.[image: See photo.] I just suspect It should be translated to logic as ∀X((X ∈ m) → (A(Δaeb) + A(Δdec) = 1/2A(ABCD)). So it says for every point X, if X is on the midsegment, then area of those two triangles equals the area of the trapezoid itself.

How can I verify this? Is there's a general way of verifying that the sentence is properly translated from English to predicate logic? Is there's any recommendations of how not to mess up? That is pretty simple sentence, but even though, I can't be sure it translated properly. And nothing to say about more complicated sentences. Thank you. That will be really helpful not only for me, but to others who have the same problems. There are a lot of direct translations of sentences, but no general ways of doing so. I don't trust my intuition alone! :)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how much detail you want to put In the statement. What you wrote is correct assuming you have given a definition of m (to say that X ∈ m) and the areas created with those points. 
But, if you use a quantifier, the variable you declared should appear in the expression (when you write A(Δaeb) you could write this in terms of X and the other points)
You can also write ∀X ∈ m instead of declaring X and then saying where it belongs.
A nice book to get started in logics is "How to prove it"